# Understanding the proof of Friedrichs inequality (pde)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

This is a proof of Friedrich's inequality from a set of lecture notes on PDE:
(Friedrich's Inequality).

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded and consider $p \in[1, \infty)$. Then, there exists a constant $c(\Omega)>0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_{L_p(\Omega)} \leq c(\Omega)\|\nabla u\|_{L_p(\Omega)}, \quad u \in W_p^1(\Omega) .
$$
PROOF. Choose $R>0$ such that $\Omega \subset[-R, R]^n$. Let $u \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ and write $x=(y, t) \in$ $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
u(x)=\int_{-R}^t \partial_n u(y, \tau) \mathrm{d} \tau,
$$
hence, using Hölder's inequality and $1 / p+1 / p^{\prime}=1$ when $p \in(1, \infty)$,
$$
|u(x)|^p \leq\left(\int_{-R}^t\left|\partial_n u(y, \tau)\right| \mathrm{d} \tau\right)^p \leq(2 R)^{p / p^{\prime}} \int_{-R}^t\left|\partial_n u(y, \tau)\right|^p \mathrm{~d} \tau .
$$
Integrating this inequality yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega}|u(x)|^p \mathrm{~d} x & \leq c(R) \int_{[-R, R]^n} \int_{-R}^t\left|\partial_n u(y, \tau)\right|^p \mathrm{~d} \tau \mathrm{d}(y, t) \\
& \leq c(R) \cdot 2 R \int_{[-R, R]^n}\left|\partial_n u(x)\right|^p \mathrm{~d} x \leq c_1(R) \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u(x)|^p \mathrm{~d} x
\end{aligned}
$$
where we used Fubini's theorem for the second inequality. This shows that
$$
\|u\|_{L_p(\Omega)} \leq c(\Omega)\|\nabla u\|_{L_p(\Omega)}
$$
for each $u \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$. The density of $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ in $W_p^1(\Omega)$ shows that this inequality is also true for $u \in \dot{W}_p^1(\Omega)$

I could not follow the proof after the line: "Integrating this inequality yields...". It seems a lot of details were missing.

Also, why does showing the inequality hold for all test functions show it holds for the entire space? I know test functions are dense, but how do we get from one side of the inequality to the other?

Comment: To answer your last question: you can take $\phi_n \to \phi$ in $W_1^p$ with $\phi_n$ smooth. You have the inequality for each $n$, and then taking a limit of both sides proves it holds for $\phi$ (since the convergence is in $W_1^p$).

Comment: Please give the reference to the lecture notes on PDE you mention. It can be of interest for us to see exactly the presentation therein.